# How to handle object list request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to read a list of objects

```
[
  {
    "name" : "Jhone",
    "age" : 25
  }, 
  {
    "name" : "Chris",
    "age" : 24
  }
]
```

How to handle that types of request?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? what do you want to do with it? what type of "handling" are you trying to achieve? maybe you need to take a look at [Ruby Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html) and [Ruby Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html) classes.

Comment: what exactly you want to do with the array

Comment: we handle this request in java (Spring boot) like
@RequestBody List<User> request 
how to catch this request in ROR

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the array to access each object by its key. Assuming that array of objects is set to a variable called array

```
array.each { |element| puts element["name"] }
```

Btw, the objects are incorrectly formatted. You need a comma after each name value.

Comment: thanks for your answer
but how to catch request without key like java 
@Reqeustbody List<User> request

Comment: Where is that data coming from? You need to provide more information. Is that from an api call? Wherever its coming from, set it equal to a variable which you can loop through.